# how to upload data to apple developer device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

If I am using xcode's simulator I can upload data to the app folder (/APPID/Documents) easily.

Can push data directly to an developer device too?

The data itself is mainly xml files for the app to interact with.

The reason to do this is to make a mock-up for a presentation.

Comment: Did you consider trying first? Since SO is not a discussion board, it would seem to make sense to first try, and if you can't make it work then post asking for alternatives / help. Since I think it won't work directly, I will suggest you could include your xml files in your bundle resources even if they shouldn't live there long-term... just to have a dev-version of your app copy them where you want them to live.

Comment: i did try via finder but that did not work. i will try your bundle advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via the Organizer.

1. in Organizer->Devices
2. select the device on the left side
3. select the Application you are working on
4. on the bottom select "Download". This downloads a .xcappdata
5. Right click and "Show Package Contents" on the .xcappdata and there you'll see the Documents folder
6. Add what ever you want to the Documents folder
7. Go back to Organizer and click this time Upload, select the modified .xcappdata.

That should make the data available in the Documents file. Keep in mind that the app had to be installed on the device once, before you can access it on the Organizer.

Also, it could take quite some time if the data are heavy files. But as you just want the xmls it shouldn't be a problem.

**[EDIT]**
[image]

Comment: i tried that before but i do not see any applications there. maybe i installed my app wrong? i normally just launch it via xcode and unplug the device. do i need to make an archive which i normally do for the app store?

Comment: Hmmm... it should be enough if you launch it via xCode. What version of xCode are you using?

Comment: Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)

Comment: I have the same version... just to make sure I have edited the answer adding a screenshot of how I see it in Organizer. If you don't see those apps not sure what could be going wrong.

Comment: thats where i have 2 blank areas instead. thank you for your help so far. however i can see those entries on my iPod which does not support iOS7 (therefore is no longer in use)

Comment: now i fixed it! i made a new provisioning profile for distribution (my old worked but apparently produced this bug) and now i can see my app and its sandbox data!

Comment: furthermore i needed to uninstall the app from the device